# Get VirtualBox id (uuid) from Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to discover the uuid of a newly created vm from inside its Vagrantfile. I know the value is there somewhere, but I can't seem to dig it out.

The value would be used in an embedded `VBoxManage` command:

```ruby
%x(VBoxManage guestproperty get #{vm.id} "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/1/V4/IP")
```

Two possible workarounds:

First, just set a unique name for the VM and use that:

```ruby
v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "My unique VM name"]
```

Second, might be reading the contents of `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id` though that feels kind of terrible.

Answer (score 1):

> Second, might be reading the contents of
>   .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id though that feels kind of
>   terrible.

why its terrible ? this file contains only the Id itself so there's no parsing and the file is there for each and every provider

something like this will work directly

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  p "read id " + File.read(".vagrant/machines/default/vmware_fusion/index_uuid")
```

so will give you

```
$ vagrant up
"read id 678add84e58c4c918d498a2b629f30f7"
```

Comment: The `id` is already somewhere in Vagrant's `vm` object. Several plug-ins are able to expose the value, so reading the it back in from disk feels like a hack.

Comment: well plugins can access the `@ENV` and access `machine` and `machine.id` indeed and I am not sure you can (not enough experience with ruby). also if you had access to the `id` from Vagrantfile you would not need to pass `"modifyvm", :id --name` parameter specific for each provider but then you would do `vb.id = xxx` which is not what vagrant documents